# Bookmarking / Highlighting lines in a file

Tags: highlighting, bookmarks, navigation

Is there an Emacs feature for highlighting some lines in a file to make it easier to jump around? My immediate use-case is a gigantic auto-generated C++ file with horrible indentation, which is rather difficult to navigate and it's easy to get lost. At the moment, I'm adding comments of the form `// LOC-1` to find where I've just been, but that feels a bit icky.

I know that some other text editors have this tied in with their bookmark mechanism (sublime text?) and you can add a blue blob to the left gutter. Maybe there's a way to show Emacs bookmarks in the gutter? Or maybe there's a different feature that shows something like this or highlighted lines?

I'm not concerned with this persisting across closing and opening the file, or with multiple buffers viewing it: either persistent or not is fine with me.

Is there an easy way for me to leave myself some "breadcrumbs"?

Comment: The answer I gave is more in line with your question, however, I wanted to mention `evil-mode` which emulates vim.  This allows you to set "invisible" marks.  For example `mm` would create a mark named "m" and `ma` would create a mark called "a".  You could then navigate to line "m" with `'m` and navigate to line "a" with `'a`.  You could navigate to the marked position on "m" with `\`m` and the marked position on "a" with `\`a`.  Of course, `evil` has a learning curve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  One of my preferred methods is the [`bm`](https://github.com/joodland/bm) package.  The package provides visual bookmarks:

[image]

The setup is dead simple:

```
(require 'bm)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-f2>") 'bm-toggle)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>")   'bm-next)
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-f2>") 'bm-previous)
```

You can change the color of the bookmark with

```
(set-face-attribute 'bm-face nil :background "RoyalBlue4" :foreground 'unspecified)
```

Use the `list-colors` command to find something more suitable to your theme than `RoyalBlue4`.

Comment: I'd recommend to use instead of C-f2 better s-f2 as C-f2 is set to switch Desktops in some Linux versions

Answer (score 1):

`bm.el` may do what you request, but [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) does everything that `bm.el` does, and much more.  And it uses the same kind of bookmarks that vanilla Emacs uses. Emacs bookmarks record more information than just a location.

Relevant to your request, you can have:

- [Autonamed bookmarks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks), which are quick to create, move, and delete.
- [Automatic, idle-period bookmarking](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutomaticBookmarking)
- [Temporary bookmarks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#TemporaryBookmarks) (as an alternative to the usual, persistent bookmarks).
- Many different ways to [highlight bookmark locations](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#HighlightingBookmarkLocations) (visual bookmarks), automatically or on demand, generally or according to bookmark type.  Likewise, unhighlighting. You can even specify particular highlighting to use for individual bookmarks.
- [Acting in various ways](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#UsingHighlightedBookmarks) on only highlighted (or unhighlighted) bookmarks.
- [Temporary crosshairs highlighting](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#DestinationHighlighting) of arrival location after jumping.
- Multiple ways to navigate among bookmarks, including quickly *cycling* among any set of them as a [navigation list](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#CyclingNavlist).